# Calibration of G2++ two factor interest rate model using Kalman filtering

Tags: interest-rates, calibration, kalman

I'm trying to use the Kalman filter to calibrate a G2++ interest rate model in R. I'm reading "Implementing interest rate models: A practical guide" by Park F.C. (2004) where he provides details on how to set it up. Although I can follow the equations described in the paper I'm lacking the understanding of how everyhting is combined together and the order I should follow in order to calibrate the G2++ model parameters. I would be greatful if someone can provide a schematic or pseudo-code that either follows this paper or any other relevant one.

Comment: Have you checked the answer to this question?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484572/one-factor-mean-reverting-model-parameter-estimation-with-kalman-filter-linalg/484624#484624